# JavaFX TabPane does not forward click events when tab reordering is enabled

Tags: java, javafx

In my JavaFX application there is a `TabPane` with several tabs. Each of those tabs has a special control, let's say a `Label`, that is attached to the tab via its `setGraphic` method. The custom controls are supposed to do something when the user double-clicks them, so they get an event handler assigned with `setOnMouseClicked`.

So far this is fine and works as expected. However, it should also be possible for users to reorder the tabs by drag and drop. This can be done by setting the TabPane's tabDragPolicy to `TabPane.TabDragPolicy.REORDER`, but unfortunately the click event handlers are then no longer working/being called. See below for a simple example that shows this behaviour.

Is this a bug/shortcoming of JavaFX? I'm using OpenJFX 17. My first guess would be that maybe the implementation of the reordering "swallows" the click events. Could I do something differently to avoid this? Is there a workaround to get both reordering as well as events in the case of double clicks?

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Label label1 = new Label("Label 1");
        label1.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            if(event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY && event.getClickCount() == 2) {
                System.out.println("Label 1 double clicked!");
            }
        });

        Label label2 = new Label("Label 2");
        label2.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            if(event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY && event.getClickCount() == 2) {
                System.out.println("Label 2 double clicked!");
            }
        });

        Tab tab1 = new Tab();
        tab1.setGraphic(label1);

        Tab tab2 = new Tab();
        tab2.setGraphic(label2);

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab1);
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab2);

        // The event handlers above stop being called when this line is active
        //tabPane.setTabDragPolicy(TabPane.TabDragPolicy.REORDER);
        
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(tabPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```